# What are the minimum binaries needed to run Gallio with MbUnit tests

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, mbunit, gallio

We recently upgraded our application to .Net 4.0. We were using MbUnit 2.x. With the upgrade to .Net 4.0 the MbUnit tests don't seem to run. Rather than fighting with it I decided to upgrade to MbUnit v3 which ships with Gallio test runners.

I would like to put the minimum required binaries/files into a Nant folder in the third party folder of our project folder that is checked into svn. This way the build server and devs can run the unit tests without needing to install Gallio/MbUnit.

What is The minimum lists of binaries/config files needed for MbUnit tests and to run Icarus and Echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=gallio:installation

better late than never :)